# About classpath:/META-INF/resources in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, swagger

I am using below content to configure the swagger in springmvc.xml.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="swagger-ui.html" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**"
    location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" />
```

But I does not understand the internal. Why can i visit http://localhost:3333/swagger-ui.html?
There are so many jar files in my project. Why the path swagger-ui.html will point to the content under **springfox-swagger-ui-2.6.1.jar!\META-INF\resources\webjars\springfox-swagger-ui**.  Why doesn't it look for the web content under other jar file? How does it work? Thanks.